# How to have a fractional environment number

Tags: numbering, theorems, cleveref, fractions

For kind of a gag, i want to have a theorem with a fractional number. It is perfectly fine if i have to give the number specifically.

However, i do **not** want to define a new environment for this, since i want to reuse the styling of the theorem and want it to change with it in case i change the layout of the theorem.

I tried something like `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{9$\fraction{3}{4}}`, but this does not work since `\refstepcounter` (which is called automatically by the theorem) just overwrites this, and i do not know how to prevent this.

I know this is kind of silly and serves no real purpose, but it is still something funny i would like to do.

---

Edit:

I use `thmtools` for producing my theorem environments, but that does not seem to be a problem, it still works.

However, my problem seems to be a combination of the package `cleveref` and the fact that I actually want this to work for a definition that shares its counter with theorem. If i use `cleveref` and only the theorem, everythin is fine. If I don't use `cleveref`, the below code also works for the definition, sharing its counter with theorem.

But as soon as I use both of them, i get compiling errors and the Definition is messed up. The warnings also don't seem to help me.

Below is a MWE (that works when commenting out `cleveref`, but fails when the package is used):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}
See Theorem~\ref{thm:first}, Theorem~\ref{thm:second} or Theorem~\ref{thm:third} or Definition~\ref{def:third}.

\begin{theorem}
  First theorem.\label{thm:first}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Second]
  Second theorem.\label{thm:second}
\end{theorem}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \refstepcounter
%\stepcounter{theorem}% Step default theorem counter % Commented out because using hyperref
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}$\mathbf{\tfrac{3}{4}}$}% Setup printing of theorem counter
\begin{theorem}
  Third theorem.%
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{theorem}$\tfrac{3}{4}$}% Update theorem reference
  \makeatother
  \label{thm:third}% Capture reference in \label
\end{theorem}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \refstepcounter
%\stepcounter{theorem}% Step default theorem counter % Commented out because using hyperref
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}$\mathbf{\tfrac{3}{4}}$}% Setup printing of theorem counter
\begin{definition}
  Third theorem.%
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{theorem}$\tfrac{3}{4}$}% Update theorem reference
  \makeatother
  \label{def:third}% Capture reference in \label
\end{definition}
\endgroup

\begin{theorem}
  Fifth theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Produced output with cleveref]

Comment: What package are you using to produce your theorems?

Comment: `\refstepcounter` does not change the definition of `\thetheorem` . What you show shoudl work with most theorem definitions if you added the missing `$` but as you have shown no example it is impossible to say why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do some manual legwork, but it's doable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

See Theorem~\ref{thm:first}, Theorem~\ref{thm:second} or Theorem~\ref{thm:third}.

\begin{theorem}
  First theorem.\label{thm:first}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Second]
  Second theorem.\label{thm:second}
\end{theorem}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \refstepcounter
\stepcounter{theorem}% Step default theorem counter
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}$\mathbf{\tfrac{3}{4}}$}% Setup printing of theorem counter
\begin{theorem}
  Third theorem.%
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{theorem}$\tfrac{3}{4}$}% Update theorem reference
  \makeatother
  \label{thm:third}% Capture reference in \label
\end{theorem}
\endgroup

\begin{theorem}
  Fourth theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

It seems to be sufficient to remove `\stepcounter{theorem}` if you're using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well.

Comment: Yes, i do use hyperref, and your solution works. However, there seems to be a problem with `cleveref`, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\tag` command from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a = b + c
\tag{9$\frac{3}{4}$}
\label{eq:ntf}
\end{equation}

Look at Equation \ref{eq:ntf} to find $a$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that this is not what i wanted. At least, i don't know how I can get this to work for the numbering of the theorem/definition. If you think this is possible, could you provide more details?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler this is an equation, which is not the same as a theorem although it can be used to express theorems as well. The number between the parentheses is the equation number - if you don't use `\tag` then this is auto-numbered. Your question is probably better answered by the other answer that uses explicit theorems, however this answer may be useful for other people that are interested in alternative numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the “gag” takes as main number the last theorem number, it's easier…

Just some care is needed to please `hyperref` and assign a unique anchor name. We also need to convince `amsthm` to use boldface math in the theorem head. Note that `cleveref` should go after `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newcounter{gag}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{gag}[1]{%
  \let\savedthetheorem\thetheorem
  \thm@headfont{\bfseries\boldmath}%
  \stepcounter{gag}%
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\savedthetheorem#1}%
  \renewcommand{\theHtheorem}{gag\thegag}%
  \addtocounter{theorem}{-1}\ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See \Cref{thm:first}, \Cref{thm:second} or 
\Cref{thm:third} or \Cref{def:third}.

\begin{theorem}
First theorem.\label{thm:first}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Second]
Second theorem.\label{thm:second}
\end{theorem}

\begin{gag}{$\frac{3}{4}$}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:third}
Third theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{gag}

\begin{gag}{$\frac{3}{4}$}
\begin{definition}\label{def:third}
Definition.
\end{definition}
\end{gag}

\begin{theorem}
Fifth theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]